# Occasional 'Conversation not found' error when sending proactive messages with a Teams bot

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-teams-js

I am developing a custom Teams app consisting of a tab app and a bot app. The bot app is designed to send Adaptive Cards triggered by an external HTTP POST request. The accountId in the POST request determines which user's bot app the card is sent to.
The accountId means aadObjectId.

However, I occasionally encounter a 'Conversation not found' error when sending these Adaptive Cards. This happens inconsistently, even with the same user, and can occur even if the user has not uninstalled the app.

Here are some details about the app:

1. The conversation ID is obtained from the first conversation with the user and is stored in an Azure storage account.
2. The conversation ID is not updated once it has been obtained.
3. The bot is used in a 1:1 chat.
4. The conversation ID is obtained from the tab app's context.

I have checked the official Microsoft documentation and understand that this error can occur if the bot does not have access to the team or channel, or if the conversation ID is incorrect. However, I am not sure why this error is occurring inconsistently and how to fix it.

Does anyone have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, are there any cases where the conversation ID gets updated? If you know, please let me know.

Expectation:

- To be able to send Adaptive Cards without encountering the 'Conversation not found' error.

What I checked:

- The chat has not been deleted on the Teams side.
- The app has not been uninstalled.

Comment: As you mention, Occasional 'Conversation not found' error then Could you please share Bot Id and timestamp, so that we can investigate it from our end?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same... The user did not delete the conversation and has not uninstalled the bot, yes we randomly get the ConversationNotFound message

Comment: "ConversationNotFound" means the conversation ID is invalid. In general, the error "Conversation not found" happens when the conversation doesn't exist or has been deleted. Which means Some user operations, such as blocking the bot or deleting the bot, may impact that ID.
Could you please confirm that the conversation ID that you are storing in the database is the same one that you are using for sending proactive messages?

Comment: We're having this exact issue. Did someone manage to fix it?

Comment: We have already raised the bug for the same. we will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: Does this fixed @Sayali-MSFT? or do we need to have mechanism to update the stored conversation id?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT What other id get impacted when user delete or block the bot? is there any docs for this?